# Using Invoke-Command to Get Application Pools on Remote Servers

Tags: arrays, powershell, iis, powershell-5.0

I'm attempting to use Invoke-Command to get a list of application pools on multiple remote servers.  So far I have something like:

```
$servers = Get-Content -Path "C:\Path\to\servers.txt"

$array = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.ArrayList'

foreach ($server in $servers) {
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
Import-Module WebAdministration
$sites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\sites
    foreach ($site in $sites) {
        $array.Add($site.bindings)}}}
```

However I get the error:

```
 You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Add:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
    + PSComputerName        : computername
```

I've tried using regular arrays instead of ArrayLists and I get the following error:

```
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
    + PSComputerName        : computername
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can't add objects from a remote session to an array that exists on your local computer. Have the `Invoke-Command` block return the Bindings and then pick up the results in the outer foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Your object `$array`is not known on your remote servers. So, one proposition is to send your array to the remote server, then add some values and return it :

```
$servers = Get-Content -Path "C:\Path\to\servers.txt"
```

$array = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.ArrayList'

```
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $array = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
      param($array)
      Import-Module WebAdministration
      $sites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\sites
      foreach ($site in $sites) {
         [void]($array.Add($site.bindings))
      }
      $array
     } -ArgumentList $array
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting a "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." error unfortunately.  Thanks for reply, though.

Comment: I edited my answer, but i can't test now but the idea is there.